# Proof by Induction: $(1+x)^n \le 1+(2^n-1)x$

Tags: analysis, induction

I have to prove the following by induction:

$$(1+x)^n \le 1+(2^n-1)x$$

for $n \ge 1$ and $0 \le x \le 1$.

I start by showing that it's true for $n=1$ and assume it is true for one $n$.

$$(1+x)^{n+1} = (1+x)^n(1+x)$$
by assumption:
$$\le (1+(2^n-1)x)(1+x)$$
$$= 1+(2^n-1)x+x+(2^n-1)x^2$$

That is what I was able to do on my own. I do not understand the next step of the solution (they are now using $x$ instead of $x^2$ at the end):

$$Because\,0 \le x \le 1$$
$$(1+x)^{n+1} \le 1 + (2^n-1)x+x+(2^n-1)x$$
$$=1+2(2^n-1)x+x$$
$$=1+(2^{n+1}-1)x$$

Because $0 \le x \le 1$ I assume that $(2^n-1)x^2 < (2^n-1)x$. So in my opinion, I just proved that $(1+x)^{n+1}$ is less than something *greater* than what I had to prove initially. Why is it enough to prove the original problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear as to what your final sentence means. But, since $0\le x\le 1$, we know that $x^2\le x\cdot x\le 1\cdot x\le x$, so that
$$(1+x)^{n+1} \le 1 + (2^n-1)x + x + (2^n-1)x^2
    \le 1 + (2^n-1)x + x + (2^n-1)x = 1+2(2^n-1)x + x = 1 + (2^{n+1}-1)x,$$
which is the statement for $n+1$.

Comment: Oh wow. Looks like my brain does not recognize the simplest things after all the learning in the past few weeks. After reading your answer everything was clear.
No idea what my problem was, I guess definitely need some sleep.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+x)^{n+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^{n}\le(1+x)(1+(2^{n}-1)x)=1+(2^{n}-1)x+x(1+(2^{n}-1)x)$$

$$\underbrace{\le}_{x\le1}1+(2^{n}-1)x+x(1+2^{n}-1)=1+(2^{n}-1)x+2^{n}x$$

$$=1+(2\cdot2^{n}-1)x=1+(2^{n+1}-1)x$$